# how to connect an android app to my website database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-applications

I own a company that makes websites for sport teams. Each website has it's own admin section where coaches login and post pictures, results and news to the homepage of their website. I need to create an  app where coaches can login and upload a picture or story directly from the app without having to login to the admin section of their website. Everything needs to be done inside the app. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Add web api or web service to your site and utilize these mechanisms to connect from the app.

Comment: Hire an app developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a webservice that the app will call to do everything needs to be done by the app

Comment: You shouldn't be posting your comments as an answer.

Comment: That looks like a legit answer, a poor answer, but a answer nerveless.